# Liquid fueled suborbital rockets?

Tags: liquid-fuel, launch-vehicle

Which suborbital (sounding, balistic, amateur or else) rockets use or used liquid fuel?

I could find (with help from A. Rumlin)

- [New Shepard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Shepard) - Blue Origin - RP-1
- [Spica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_Suborbitals#Spica) - Copenhagen Suborbitals - ethanol
- [V-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-2) and derivatives - ethanol
- Zonda 1.0 - Lia Aerospace - Argentine - https://lia-aerospace.com

If the list is too long then I would like to exclude the balistic missiles.

Comment: Aerobee, MR-1, MMR-05, MMR-08, WAC Corporal

Comment: Why are you putting the answer in the question? Very bad stack exchange form. Consider copying the answer you have already started in the question to an actual answer. You could make it community wiki if you want.

Comment: Sorry about that. After your message, I flagged for making it a community wiki but it was not approved.

Comment: All the water rockets I played with as a kid were definitely sub-sub-orbital...

Comment: That is propellant, not fuel. The fuel is used to ignite and propell using combustion

Comment: @OrganicMarble If no evidence of research is seen there is [pushback](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1694/12102) so perhaps this is simply a good-faith effort to include evidence of research, i.e. "Here is what I've found so far"?

Comment: I did include some rockets from the moment I first asked this question, so there was research from the begining. I just wanted to make the list larger, since Rumlin posted those rocket names in a comment. But it would be nice if it would be transformed into a community wiki

Comment: @uhoh: But posting the answer in an answer, which is where answers belong, would have had the same effect. There's a reason why the question asking dialog directly includes a button to post an answer together with the question, after all.

Comment: I removed the items mentioned by A. Rumlin and I present my apologies

Comment: create an answer, and put the ones you have in there, then make the answer a community wiki

Comment: @JörgWMittag I have never figured out what the reason is though. It seems like a handy option that the site makes available, but it's existence does not in any way speak to us and tell us what we should not do. As to the "answers belong in answers" I've just written something similar [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/53546/space-shuttle-digital-signal-processor-dsp-floating-point-or-fixed-point#comment174657_53546)