# Space shuttle digital signal processor (DSP): floating point or fixed point?

Tags: launch, space-shuttle, saturn-v, guidance, computing

Digital signal processors can represent irrational numbers using fixed-point or floating-point data types.

Fixed point means fixed number of decimal places, and floating point means floating number of decimal places.

There are advantages to each and it isn't always best to use a floating-point processor.

Still, where numerical precision matters, floating-point has a leg up, and I've been assuming a launch vehicle like the space shuttle or Saturn V would have used exactly that in its GNC systems.

But have I been assuming right? Or might it have been fixed-point instead?

Not a computer scientist. I know just enough about data types to get me in trouble. Please hold down your bazookas, kind people :D

**Update**

Just found [the text below](https://www.history.nasa.gov/computers/Ch4-3.html) suggesting the space shuttle in fact used fixed-point arithmetic. Now wondering if modern rockets use fixed-point too... and can someone confirm that the excerpt below really means 480,000 instructions per second for fixed-point against 7,000 for floating-point? That difference is huuuge and unexpected to me. Big thanks if you can confirm!

[image]

Comment: That quote says the shuttle GPC used both. Where do you see 70,000? It quotes *7000 for the Gemini computer* ... what are you asking?

Comment: Ah, you're right, and yes, typo :D

Comment: *The two numbers are from two different computers, not just fixed and floating point* The point of the comparison is shuttle computer vs Gemini computer, not computation type

Comment: I retreat, I retreat, I didn't think this question through enough, I retreat :D

Comment: Don't answer your question in your question. Either delete this post (to avoid collecting down votes) or go ahead and post an answer, which is fine in Stack Exchange as long as it's a reasonable answer.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I can give an explanation of why floating point is so much slower.  Consider addition: in fixed point, it works a lot like integer addition.  Everything lines up nicely; you add the digits, handle any overflow, and you're done.  In floating point, you basically have two numbers represented in (more or less) scientific notation.  That means you first have to scale them so the exponents are the same before you can perform addition, then you have to normalize the result.  Floating point ops are quite a few more steps.

Comment: Thank you, @Tristan! I'm learning, I'm learning :D Is there a number you can put on the difference between fixed-point and floating-point speeds? An order of magnitude, ballpark figure, even if it applies only to some specific example? E.g., "fixed-point addition is 10x faster than floating-point addition?" Also: are there any operations where floating-point is as fast as fixed-point? Are there any operations where floating-point is fast*er*?

Comment: @uhoh: there's more to the question than the bit I added in my update. Will close the question soon if no more info arrives, though :)

Comment: It's really implementation-dependent.  If you **really** want to get into the weeds, check out Volume 2 of The Art of Computer Programming by Donald Knuth.

Comment: Hey that's a pretty solid reference to have. Just got a copy. Thanks for the pointer! But yeah, definitely the kind of book to read very methodically, it seems---not just a quick reference for computing things :D

Comment: @user39728_i_said_user_39728_i_ no, you should not solicit help in comments from others, then *delete the question* so future readers can not see the comments. That's unfair to the commenters (in this case Tristan) AND to future readers. You should put the question in the question post, and material that answer the question in an answer post. An SE question post is not the user's own personal workspace or chat room. SE works so well because people stick to the standards. We don't delete questions after we've learned as much as we can.

Comment: I'm not sure that "[Digital Signal Processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor)" means what you think it means. "Digital signal processing" refers to numerical techniques for analyzing images, sounds, and other "[continuous phennomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_(measurement))", and DSP hardware is computing machinery that is highly specialized for that task. The [AP-101](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/4_Pi) that you cite was _functionally_ a general-purpose computer, even though it was physically specialized for aerospace applications.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Agreed! NASA even referred to it as the General Purpose Computer (GPC) https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/shuttle/flyout/flyfeature_shuttlecomputers.html

Comment: @uhoh: I couldn't care less who reads this question. I deleted it because it seemed clear it was a poor question. You seem to like deleting other peoples' questions when you decide they're poor, so I don't get your beef with my proactively deleting my poor questions. To the others: I ask because clearly I don't know the answer nor do I have the luxury of knowing enough to ask a good proper question. Or I wouldn't be wasting my time here. Which frankly now seems a fine idea. No one's got time for pompous cranky answers that merely point out the obvious and then abuse you for not knowing better.

Comment: @user39728_i_said_user_39728_i_ Questions are *closed* all the time and closing blocks further answers. If it's answer-blocking you want then that's how it's done. However questions are very very rarely *deleted* and the only time that happens is when they are incredibly low quality (e.g. rambling offensive noise by unregistered users or spam).  So "You seem to like deleting other peoples' questions when you decide they're poor..." is not right. Closing allows the OP the possibility to decide at some point in the future to go back and revise the question.

Comment: @user39728_i_said_user_39728_i_ anyway, you of course *can* delete your question; there's no rule against it and I certainly can't tell you not to. I've certainly deleted a few of my own questions when I decided they weren't viable. But whenever I feel there is some information potentially useful to others (or to me) in the future, I just leave them there or if I 'm worried about down votes I start the close process. Closed questions are generally left alone by down voters here in Space SE, but they are still searchable and so the information is available for reuse in the future.

Comment: @user39728_i_said_user_39728_i_ here is an example of a question that has an actual *delete* vote in addition to being closed: [Why does modern space exploration… suck](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53570/12102)